# HD wallet getting every time diffrent derivedPrivatekey from same derivation path

Tags: bitcoin-core

every time i am getting diffrent orderPrivateKey and address for same derivation path. but it should be same as i am not changing derivation path.

```
var bitcore = require('bitcore-lib');
var DerivationPath = "m/44'/145'/0'/0"
var hdPrivateKey = new bitcore.HDPrivateKey('testnet','xprv8ZgxMBicQKsPdsKyyKSwTJtBXWB1rbDwEAxW3xV6xwNeCHs3n9kvFsCZim8KKMgc3wVGRJR4kJ82t9mRRr8TZ3Ybpxqp8brRA7aMVDJgCt2');
var orderPrivateKey  = hdPrivateKey.derive(DerivationPath).privateKey;
var Address = orderPrivateKey.toAddress().toString();
```

can anyone explain it??

Answer (score 1):

You have the `data` and `network` arguments swapped when you create the `hdPrivateKey`, see [Private Key | Bitcore](https://bitcore.io/api/lib/private-key#new_PrivateKey_new). Try this:

```
var bitcore = require('bitcore-lib');
var DerivationPath = "m/44'/145'/0'/0"
var hdPrivateKey = new bitcore.HDPrivateKey('xprv9s21ZrQH143K3QTDL4LXw2F7HEK3wJUD2nW2nRk4stbPy6cq3jPPqjiChkVvvNKmPGJxWUtg6LnF5kejMRNNU3TGtRBeJgk33yuGBxrMPHi', 'testnet');
var orderPrivateKey  = hdPrivateKey.derive(DerivationPath).privateKey;
var Address = orderPrivateKey.toAddress().toString();
console.log('Address: ' + Address);
```